# Bison lanza excepción "terminales inútiles en la gramática"

Tags: bison, yacc

tengo un problema con la implementación de esta gramática en Bison. Obtengo el error "terminales inútiles en la gramática" en referencia al símbolo no-terminal "expresión" y creo que está bien definido.

No alcanzo a ver el fallo. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

```
//Prioridades
%left '-' //unitario
%right EXP
%left '*' '%' MOD
%left '+'
%left '&'
%left '@'
%nonassoc '=' DISTINTO '<' '>' MENOR_IGUAL MAYOR_IGUAL 
%nonassoc NOT
%left AND
%left OR

%%


lineas:
      | lineas linea
;

linea: '\n'
     | expresion '\n'                   { printf ("Resultado: %f\n", $1); }
     | error '\n'                       { yyerrok; }
;


expresion: '-' expresion                      { $$ = -$2; }           // menos (unitario)
           | expresion EXP expresion          { $$ = pow($1, $3); }  // potencia
           | expresion '*' expresion          { $$ = $1 * $3; }      // multiplicacion
           | expresion '%' expresion          { $$ = $1 / $3; }      // division
           | expresion MOD expresion          { $$ = $1 % $3; }      // Modulo
           | expresion '+' expresion          { $$ = $1 + $3; }      // suma
           | expresion '-' expresion          { $$ = $1 - $3; }      // resta
           | expresion '&' expresion          { $$ = $1*$3; }        // AND binario
           | expresion '@' expresion          { $$ = $1+$3; }        // OR binario
           | expresion MENOR_IGUAL expresion  { $$ = $1 <= $3; }      // <= 
           | expresion MAYOR_IGUAL expresion  { $$ = $1 >= $3; }      // >=
           | expresion DISTINTO expresion     { $$ = $1 != $3; }      // !=
           | expresion '<' expresion          { $$ = $1 < $3; }      // <
           | expresion '>' expresion          { $$ = $1 > $3; }      // >
           | expresion '=' expresion          { $$ = $1 == $3; }     // ==
           | NOT expresion                    { $$ = !$1; }          // NOT
           | expresion AND expresion          { $$ = $1 && $3; }     // AND
           | expresion OR expresion           { $$ = $1 || $3; }     // OR
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Todas las producciones para `expresión` son recursivas. Sin por lo menos una producción no recursiva, la derivación no termina nunca. Asimismo,  ningún producción permita un número ni un identificador.

Así que Bison lo elimina por falta de utilidad.

Comment: Y cómo puedo implementar una regla `expresion` no recursiva de forma en que se mantenga la funcionalidad del programa? Se podría hacer de forma `expresion: /*cadena vacía*/` y el resto de reglas recursivas?

Comment: `expresion: %empty`  no tiene sentido. `(+)` es una expresión por si acaso? Pero `2+2` sí. O incluso `42`. Y ¿dónde está la regla que diga que un número es una expresión? Sería una producción no rescursiva, ¿no es cierto?